# How to print user email using vehicle user_id in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and mysql in my app. and I am new to the Laravel. I have following table as vehicles,

```
id  name  number  user_id
1   car   123        1
2   van   258        2
3   lorry 125        5
4   car   896        7
```

and user table like this,

```
id name    email
1  hyu     agt@mail.com
2  opv     yyuj@mail.com
3  kio     juik@mail.com
4  lop     kiuf@mail.com
5  hyg     htgd@mail.com
```

Now I need print email using above vehicles table user_id in my blade file, how can I do this?
**Edit**
I have following blade file to print vehicles table,

```
{{$vehicle->name}}
{{$vehicle->number}}
```

**edit**
my vehiclecontroller,

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::find($id);


        return view('vehicles.show')->withVehicles($vehicles);
    }
```

and show blade file,

```
<div class="col-md-5" id="vl"> 
<div><label >Brand:</label>{{$vehicles->name}}</div>
<br>
<div><label >Model:</label>{{$vehicles->number}}</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Where is your code and what error you are getting?

Comment: actually I am finding a way to print email using user_id in the vehicles table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relation in place on your `Vehicle` model which looks like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

you can simply access the `user` property to get the `email`: `{{ $vehicle->user->email }}`

For improved performance, it makes sense to eager load the users when you fetch the vehicles from the database:

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('user')->get();
```

Comment: with above controller function may I return view of vehicle data print?

Comment: What exactly is your controller and blade code so far? Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: In case you only load one model (`Vehicle::find($id)`), you don't necessarily have to eager load the `user` relation. It will be loaded on first access. But you could still use `Vehicle::with('user')->find($id)` in your controller instead. Anyway, using `$vehicles->user->email` in the blade template will work if you have above mentioned relation on your `Vehicle` model.

Comment: By the way, be careful with how you name your variables. Having a variable `$vehicles` suggests that it contains a list of `Vehicles` and not only one single `Vehicle`. So to be correct, you should differentiate between `$vehicles = Vehicle::get()` and `$vehicle = Vehicle::find($id)`. This makes the code a lot more maintainable.

Comment: change Vehicle model relationship like this, **public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}**  and now working

Comment: Sure, I made a mistake there. The models are of course already in the same namespace. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) to create model for tables and then you can join it for both the tables and get user email too.

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::select('vehicles.name', 'vehicles.number', 'users.email')
        ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'vehicles.user_id')->get();
```

You can also use [Laravel relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) to achieve this.

Comment: where should I put this in My controller?

Comment: Yes you should put it in your controller and send that vehicles data to view.

Comment: then how can I print email in my view file? I mean {{$vehicles->email}} is ok?

Answer (score 0):

```
$userEmails= DB::table('vehicles')
            ->join('contacts', 'user.id', '=', 'vehicles.user_id')
            ->select('users.email')
            ->get();
```

Try above code.
This is SQL join concept. 
For your reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

Comment: where should I put this in My controller?

Comment: Put in the function you call on page load or if you want to retrieve on a click event or any other event, use AJAX and point out the respective controller and function via routes.php